# Pandas - manipulating column based on multiple condition on dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns, column fruit has values 0 or 1 and the other column as qty which has missing values with float values.

Now, I need to overwrite the qty column with a condition such as if fruit column has value as 1 and if qty column is missing then replace the qty column with 0 else same value as qty.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Dj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'qty': [np.nan,np.nan,10,23, np.nan],
    'fruit': [1,0,1,0,1]
})
print (df)
    qty  fruit
0   NaN      1
1   NaN      0
2  10.0      1
3  23.0      0
4   NaN      1

mask = (df['fruit'] == 1) & (df['qty'].isna())
df['qty'] = np.where(mask, 0, df['qty'])
```

Another solutions:

```
df.loc[mask, 'qty'] = 0
df['qty'] = df['qty'].mask(mask, 0)

print (df)
    qty  fruit
0   0.0      1
1   NaN      0
2  10.0      1
3  23.0      0
4   0.0      1
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and alternate ways to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = df[df.fruit == 1].fillna(0)
df.update(df1)
print(df)
```

df is your original dataframe .

you can add `df.fruit = df.fruit.astype(int)` before printing the df if you like.